# Returning a DBNull for a bound MaskedTextBox whenever type validation fails?

Tags: c#, validation, data-binding, dbnull, maskedtextbox

I have a MaskedTextBox control with the mask "00/00/0000", the PromptChar "_" and the ValidatingType of DateTime, bound to a DateTime column in a database that can also accept null values.

I'd like the user to have to enter either a valid date, or leave it blank (i.e. "__/__/____") for a DBNull.

By using the TypeValidationCompleted event I can determine whether a valid date was entered but I do not know how to set the value to a DBNull whenever no date, or an invalid one, is specified.

*How can I get a DBNull value from the MaskedTextBox whenever validation fails?*

Comment: Sounds like you actually want to accept any value (i.e. no validation), should try to parse the input as Date and interpret failure as DBNull.

Comment: I'd still like the input mask to be displayed in the field though, and if I dropped type validation I'd no longer be able to use the `TypeValidationCompleted` event?